# How to handle different sized phones using same density qualifier

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created an android app and have started testing it on different devices, but I've come across a problem.

My app has numerous dimens.xml for each density qualifier, but a couple of phones I'm using (Huawei P20 pro and P9) both use the dimens.xml from the xxhdpi folder, but these phones are very different in physical size/resolution. This has meant that on the smaller phone I'm getting couple of text views overlapping which doesn't look good.

The text strings are defined in sp, and all margins using dp. The textviews themselves are centred on guidelines which are defined as a percentage of the screen.

Here's a rough sketch of my layout. The textviews are in red and green, and the thin blue line represents the guidelines.

[image: diagram]

Are there any sneaky tricks I can do to get around this? The only thing I can think of is to reduce the text size and margins in the dimens.xml, but then that makes it looks worse on the larger screens (which is likely the majority).

Ideally I'd need some kind of logic in there that says if these two views overlap, reduce a margin to Xdp, or change this guideline percentage to X% etc.

**EDIT** I'm using a constraint layout, and there's currently no constraint between the green textview and the bottom red textview. I can constrain the bottom of the red textview to the top of the green textview; this solves the overlap but then it drags the red textview down on the larger screens which looks rubbish

Comment: Try to use the [smallestWidth qualifier](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources)

Answer (score 0):

> I can constrain the bottom of the red textview to the top of the green textview; this solves the overlap but then it drags the red textview down on the larger screens which looks rubbish

Set [the bias](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#adjust-the-constraint-bias) on that constraint to 0.

Answer (score 0):

you should use  layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf

reference https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout